# Updating react component from sideBar menu

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have a simple react app that consists of 3 components:
1. SideBar that contains links
2. ItemList that contains data in a table
3. Wrapper that wraps both of them (I understood from some posts here that it is sometimes useful, as I want to update the ItemsList component after clicking on different links on the sideBar).

What I have working now:

In the main Wrapper component:

```
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <SideMenu handleClick={this.handleClick} />
            <ItemsList url={this.state.currentUrl} />
        </div>
    );

}
```

as soon as the app starts, using componentDidMount() in ItemsList component, it fetches there the data, and display it. that works fine.

Problem is, when I click the links in the sideMenu component, I am changing the currentUrl in the state of the main wrapper, so then it will get re-rendered by the new url:

```
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ currentUrl: 'here I put the new address to fetch from'});
}
```

but what gets fetched is data that is located in the previous url, not the one I had just changed it to.
Basically, right after I debug and check the state after I had changed it, the currentUrl stays the previous one, and then it re-renders the ItemList with the previous url.

my question is, how do I Change the content of the itemList, using this handleClick() method? Hopefully I will get some insights. thank you very much, I would appreciate your assistance.

the main wrapper Code:

```
class MainWrapper extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        currentUrl: 'current url to fetch from...',
        data: []
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick() {
    this.setState({ currentUrl: 'the new url ' });
}


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <SideMenu handleClick={this.handleClick} />
            <ItemsList url={this.state.currentUrl} />
        </div>
    );

}
```

}

my Itemlist Component:

```
class ItemsList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { url: props.url, data: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch(this.state.url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({ data: responseJson.data });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      displaying the table html tags..

        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could the `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method in your itemList component. Each time the url changes, the listItem would presumably re-render based on what I understood from your question, so the `componentDidUpdate` method will fire. It is in this method where you can check for the new url and make the new request.

See more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

Comment: Thank you Chaim. The thing is, after I change the state, I debug it and I see that the currentUrl hasn't changed, and then the ItemList gets re-rendered, but with the previous url, not the one I wanted to change it to.

Comment: any other ideas?